# How can I create a json string in the right format with serializer (Symfony 4)?

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, encode, serialization

I am creating a json string with serializer:

```
$table = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();

$serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
$json_string = $serializer->serialize($table, 'json');
```

the result of $table:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(App\Entity\Article)#5975 (3) { ["id":"App\Entity\Article":private]=> int(1) ["title":"App\Entity\Article":private]=> string(9) "Article 1" ["body":"App\Entity\Article":private]=> string(32) "This is the body for article one" } [1]=> object(App\Entity\Article)#5979 (3) { ["id":"App\Entity\Article":private]=> int(2) ["title":"App\Entity\Article":private]=> string(11) "Article Two" ["body":"App\Entity\Article":private]=> string(32) "This is the body for article two" } }
```

This is the result of $json_string:

```
string(145) "[{"id":1,"title":"Article 1","body":"This is the body for article one"},{"id":2,"title":"Article Two","body":"This is the body for article two"}]"
```

But it is not the correct format that I need. I need it to be encoded like this:

```
{
  "recordsTotal": 10,
  "recordsFiltered": 10,
  "draw": 1,
  "data": [
    [
      "Airi",
      "Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "28th Nov 08",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica",
      "Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "9th Oct 09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton",
      "Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "12th Jan 09",
      "$86,000"
    ],
    [
      "Bradley",
      "Greer",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "13th Oct 12",
      "$132,000"
    ],
    [
      "Brenden",
      "Wagner",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "7th Jun 11",
      "$206,850"
    ],
    [
      "Brielle",
      "Williamson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "New York",
      "2nd Dec 12",
      "$372,000"
    ],
    [
      "Bruno",
      "Nash",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "3rd May 11",
      "$163,500"
    ],
    [
      "Caesar",
      "Vance",
      "Pre-Sales Support",
      "New York",
      "12th Dec 11",
      "$106,450"
    ],
    [
      "Cara",
      "Stevens",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "New York",
      "6th Dec 11",
      "$145,600"
    ],
    [
      "Cedric",
      "Kelly",
      "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "29th Mar 12",
      "$433,060"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Aproach with Normalizer:

```
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
$encoder = new JsonEncoder();
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
$json_string = $serializer->serialize($table, 'json');
```

Result:

```
string(145) "[{"id":1,"title":"Article 1","body":"This is the body for article one"},{"id":2,"title":"Article Two","body":"This is the body for article two"}]"
```

Comment: try to encapsulate `$table` ino an array with keys `recordsTotal,recordsFiltered,draw,data` , parse `$table` and get data like you want.

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud Isn't doctrine able to directly create an array with keys?

Comment: In this case, i'm not sure. you only want data without any key..it's not difficult to do it in PHP.

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud Yes you are right. I just like to keep the code as simple as possible, not creating one array and then turn it into another array. I like to have the right array directry

Comment: another solution is creating a toArray method in your entity. this will keep clean the process

Comment: I updated my question to show how table looks like

Comment: have you tried [normalizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#converting-property-names-when-serializing-and-deserializing) ?

Comment: I tested for you normalizer and posted the result in my question

Comment: i've not seen any change

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud https://i.imgur.com/A3pa9BS.png

Comment: You did not implement a custom Normalizer.

Comment: Oh ok, hm, do not know how to do this. I will try to find out!

Comment: i've sent you [this link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#converting-property-names-when-serializing-and-deserializing)

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions, but what I mean it is difficult to understand how it works.

Comment: But you think with Normalizer I can achieve this?

Comment: Their example show that, every single attributes will be prefixed by `org_`. So maybe you can just return `''`. **EDIT** Normalizer goal is to customize keys

Comment: Ok, I will let you know as soon as I can get it work. Thank you

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is from 2018. But I need to give this solution, after several hours of researching I found this:

```
$response = new Response($serializer->serialize($data, JsonEncoder::FORMAT, [JsonEncode::OPTIONS => JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT]));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

Works perfectly fine for me in Symfony 4.2

Answer (score 1):

You can control this via the `JsonSerializable` interface.

```
class Article implements JsonSerializable {
public function jsonSerialize() {
        $arr = [
            $this->firstName,
            $this->secondName,
            //...
            ];
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem, found this solution:

```
    $array = json_decode($serializer->serialize($object, 'json'), true);
    $entryJSONFile = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This actually does the trick, but I'm still not comfortable with double converting.

Comment: Actually you can avoid double convertation using normalizer only:        $array = $normalizer->normalize($object);
        $entryJSONFile = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);